# How to color D3-Geo path points in MultiPoints mode on canvas with individual colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas

In this Example of Mike Bostock https://observablehq.com/@d3/testing-projection-visibility

I created a .csv like e.g. :

```
name,longitude,latitude,color
Airport,-158.617996216,59.2826004028,white
...
```

Is it possible to apply an individual color, regarding to the .csv-value while the whole path is being generated with:

```
const path = d3.geoPath(projection, context)
      .pointRadius(1.5);

context.beginPath();
    path({type: "MultiPoint", coordinates: points});
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fill();
```

I can't find a way to apply the color from the .csv document to `context.fillStyle`...
Any ideas?

Best, hirschferkel

Comment: Kind of a duplication of this one
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529038/in-d3-geo-multipoint-how-can-i-provide-different-shapes-for-different-poins

Comment: @CarlosMoura Doesn't look like a duplicate to me, as I found it during my research, already. My question is about manipulating a path on canvas and not a SVG-path. So I think it's completely different. At least I do not now how to apply the SVG solution to Canvas at all...

Comment: yet, it refers that a Multipoint is a single entity. If you want to manipulate different individual points you can try to use a selection of several points instead of one multipoint.

Comment: @CarlosMoura ...so the easiest way to create e.g. 4 groups would be to just create 4 different Multipoints. Thus to create different selections from the csv ... did I understand it correct?

Comment: Add them as circles, a circle for each coordinate. Check here how to add them: http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/canvas/canvas_coordinates.asp.html

Comment: O.k. it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

It worked out to filter the data and create various MultiPoint Objects to e.g. filter all white elements from the Array generated from the .csv before passing it to the path generator:

```
var WhitePoints = points.filter(function (d) {return (d[3] === "white") })
```